# Is a program that checks the review section allowed?

Tags: discussion

I like reviewing people's posts, but I don't like to keep refreshing the page to see if there's a new review, and sometimes the review disapears before I even have time to click the link!

Is a program that checks the reviews every 3 seconds to see if there are new reviews and open a window on the review page allowed? The program will not answer the review for me, it will just open the review page for me.

Comment: Operation: Get All the Badges!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, first off: you'll probably find your IP blocked if you try that. Not specifically because of */review*, but because trying to scrape the site like that is an abusive waste of resources.

Beyond that... No, this still doesn't sound like a good idea. If you see something to review, go ahead and review it. Otherwise, spend some time doing other things. Answer some questions, browse around a bit, get to know the site better. Not only will this kill the time, it'll make you a *better* reviewer when you do see something to review.

Comment: Isn't clicking the refresh button every half a second a "waste of resources"?

Comment: If you do that long enough, you'll get the same result.

Answer (score 3):

While I commend you for wanting to review posts<sup>1</sup>, it would benefit the community far more if you would instead spend the time it would take to write said program **asking and answering questions**.

The honest answer is while the site has exposed editing and reviewing features to more users, the benefit to the community from your active participation in these areas is minimal. Again, where you can *really help* is asking good questions and providing good answers.

<sub>1. I may be alone in this, but I would rather you spend your first year on the site contributing with additional content and sporadically editing/reviewing. It takes a while to figure out exactly how the network operates. Spending time asking/answering questions will significantly improve the quality of your edits and reviews.</sub>

Comment: You're not alone in the opinion in the footnote; in fact, I wish it wasn't just a footnote. Although I will say that I think basic editing (for grammar and spelling) can potentially come from _any_ user.